# Is it possible to use my own sip server with voximplant engine?

Tags: voximplant

I am integrating my system with Voximplant, and i couldn't find answer in the docs, so the question is:

Is it possible to use my own sip server with voximplant engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can call any sip servers from the Voximplant Platform, for example:

```
let call = VoxEngine.callSIP("sip:alice@example.com");
```

Where instead of alice@example.com you need to use the address of your SIP server, for example **100@5.125.160.12**

https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/calls/sip